# Index Organised Table has ROW-ID?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-administration

Here is my iot table :

```
CREATE TABLE my_iot (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR2(50))
ORGANIZATION INDEX;

Insert into my_iot values(1,'Apple');
Insert into my_iot values(2,'Blackberry');
```

When i select rowid from my_iot i get the following output.
But IOT does not use ROWID so where is this rowid coming from ??
Select rowid, id from my_iot;

output :

```
ROWID                                   ID
------------------------------- ----------
*BAEADqwCwQL+                            1 
*BAEADqwCwQP+                            2
```

Comment: What database system are you actually using?

Comment: You can read about the `rowid` pseudo-column here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm.

Comment: thanks i use Oracle DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IOTs do have a ROWID. It's a logical rowid rather than the physical rowid of regular tables, but that pseudo-column does exist, and is used for secondary indexes (indexes built against the IOT).

For more details, check out the [Index-Organized Table Characteristics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/server.1111/e25789/indexiot.htm#sthref408) documentation.